# Getting a specific item value in a ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get to specific item in a ListBox (asp.net, C#)
and check if it's null or not:

```
if (ListBox.Items[0] == null )
{
     if (HowMany.Text == arrOfWords[0])
     {
          ListBox.Items.Add(arrOfWords[0]);
          ErrorMessege.Text = "Good!";
     }                    
}
```

it's returning that :  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Why is that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a null check before accessing the array elements as well.

```
if ((ListBox.Items.Count > 0) && (ListBox.Items[0] == null))
{
    if((arrOfWords.count>0)&&(arrOfWords[0]!=null))
        {
          if (HowMany.Text == arrOfWords[0])
          {
              ListBox.Items.Add(arrOfWords[0]);
              ErrorMessege.Text = "Good!";
          }
        }
}
```

**EDIT** : From your comment "***its ok that there are 0 items there for me, my intention is that if there is 0 items there, then it should add an Item from the arrOfWords***"

So if you mean, even if there are zero items in the Listbox, you need to add an item from the array to listbox, then take out the First if condition

```
if((arrOfWords.count>0)&&(arrOfWords[0]!=null))
{
   if (HowMany.Text == arrOfWords[0])
   {
       ListBox.Items.Add(arrOfWords[0]);
       ErrorMessege.Text = "Good!";
   }
}
```

Comment: in the debug mode, its not even enter the first if statement.  even if I try to make if ((ListBox.Items.Count > 0) && (ListBox.Items[0] == null))

Comment: put break points in the first if condition and see how many items are present in the list box and arrOfWords

Comment: by default, the listbox presenting 0 items when the application is running for the first time, and "arrOfWords" presenting at least one everytime.

Comment: so you have to check why listbox is having 0 items if you are expecting some items there. Where are you loading items to the list box ? Are you clearing those on a postback ?

Comment: no, its ok that there are 0 items there for me, my intention is that if there is 0 items there, then it should add an Item from the arrOfWords.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in this case the `Items` collection is empty hence even `0` is outside the bounds of the collection.  You need to test for the index being valid as well as the item being non-null.

```
if (ListBox.Items.Count > 0 && ListBox.Items[0] == null) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Then it's likely one of the other indexes. I would try the same fix for all of them.